# AtomicExchange with a particular type

Tags: delphi

I have a type :

```
type
  TDirection = (lessThan, GreaterThan);
```

and a variable

```
var MyDirection: TDirection
```

now I want to make the use of this var **threadsafe**. I would like to avoid the use of `TMonitor` for performance reason and I would prefer to use something like `AtomicExchange/AtomicCmpExchange` functions. How can I do? any other super fast way to use MyDirection in multiple Threads on macos/android/ios/win32/win64/etc.?

Comment: Have you considered [`TInterlocked`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked) yet?

Comment: `TDirection` type size is byte. Assignment of byte types are always atomic. For other purposes you can use `TInterlocked`. But your question is unclear, as thread-safe depends on what you want to do and how are you using the variable. Also atomic operations don't automatically mean some particular code is thread-safe.

Comment: You could declare your enum type to have size 4 and then use a simple cast to do atomic exchange and cmp exchange. Perhaps I am wrong but I don't think there are single byte versions.